# How to combine two rows based on multiple columns in a dataframe?

Tags: r

The title says it all, I have a  large dataset that consists of factory and latitude and longitude, and among others. some of the factories I find have identical lat long although their name slightly different. How can I combine rows of factories that have the same lat-long in R?

| mill | latitude | longitude | ID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a. | 12.34. | 7.86. | NA |
| A. | 12.34. | 7.86. | 4 |
| b | 47.56. | 27.07. | 5. |

The output I am looking for is:

| mill | latitude | longitude | ID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A. | 12.34. | 7.86. | 4 |
| b. | 47.56. | 27.07. | 5 |

Comment: Can you explain the logic to select rows? Why row 2 is selected and not 1st? For your example dropping `NA` rows with `na.omit(df)` would give the expected output shown.

Answer (score 0):

Base R

```
aggregate(.~latitude+longitude,df,tail,1)

  latitude longitude mill ID
1    12.34      7.86   A.  4
2    47.56     27.07    b  5
```

Comment: what do tail and 1 do? sorry I am a bit confuse how does it work

Comment: @FH tail function selects the last n (in our case n=1) elements (rows), in other words if there are multiple rows with the same lat/lon it selects only the last one.

Answer (score 0):

We can use

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
  arrange(latitude, longitude, is.na(ID)) %>%
  distinct(latitude, longitude, .keep_all = TRUE)
```